# Is the '@' syntax in laravel routes depreciated?

Tags: laravel

Long time since i last coded in laravel, and when i tried registering a simple route in the API routes:

```
Route::post('/register', 'AuthController@register');
```

I got "Target class [AuthController] does not exist." error. I made it work by registering with:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\AuthController;
    Route::post('/register', [AuthController::class, 'register']);
```

Confused, i gave a look at the docs and didn't find any reference to the first syntax. Is it gone and i am not knowing or i am doing something wrong?

Comment: you can still use the `@` notation but you would have to use the FQCN or have set a namespace to use ... `App\Http\Controllers\AuthController@register` ... the reason you are getting a class not found is because there is no namespace applied to these routes so it thinks you are referring to a class named `AuthController` in the root namespace .... also you should always include the version of Laravel you are using in your question

Comment: what is a FQCN?

Comment: @Kos-Mos FQCN: Fully-Qualified Class Name

Answer (score 2):

The change was introduced in Laravel 8. Previously, routes were namespaced in the `RouteServiceProvider`:

```php
// ...
protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';
```

That value comes set as `null` since v8+. That's why you have that error response. So you have two options:

- A) Add the prefix in the `RouteServiceProvider`
- B) Use the FQCN and import classes as you solved it (recommended, helps IDEs and static analysis AFAIK)